# Store a non numeric string as binary integer

Tags: c++, string, binary

How do I convert a string like

```
string a = "hello";
```

to it's bit representation which is stored in a int

```
int b = 0110100001100101011011000110110001101111
```

here `a` and `b` being equivalent.

Comment: `int`  is a 32 bit signed integer. "hello" takes 40. it's not gonna fit as it is.

Comment: You cannot. `hello` is 5 bytes, but `int` size is 4 bytes.

Comment: Are you trying to store the value of that binary representation, or the actual binary representation? Storing a binary representation in an `int` is probably a bad idea. You would likely want to store it as a string.

Comment: @litelite You can't assume `int` is 32 bits. It's only required to be at least 16.

Comment: correct, how would I do this for n<32?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I know it's not specified, but we can reasonably assume that his system use 32 bit since it's the most common value

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux For people asking a question like this, it probably is.

Comment: @Javia1492 I did read that question before posting this one. They are utilising bitset, I specifically want to store it in an int.

Comment: Well an `int` is unlikely to be big eough for anything more than `4` characters

Comment: Do you have a maximum size of string to store?

Comment: @Galik yes I am aware. I am just curious to how I would do it?

Comment: gg guys! do people here only care about _best practices_ and **don't do this** instead of helping someone experimenting with CS?

Comment: I would hope they do. Perhaps explain why you think you want to do this, to garner some support. It's hard to imagine a good reason (or event one that's fully defined behaviour)

Comment: @underscore_d I know you can calculate Hamming Distance using XOR, but to do that strings should be in form of binary.

Comment: @Siddhant The question is hard to answer completely because it doesn't make much sense: strings already  *are* stored in binary form; types like `char` and `int` are largely for the convenience of the programmer and the compiler, and you can "convert" between them simply by casting. However, depending on what you want to do with the number that results from such conversion, you might have to worry about endian issues. There are literally millions of answered questions here on SO; if you're not getting the answers you'd hoped for, the problem might be with your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot store a long character sequence (e.g. an `std::string`) inside an `int` (or inside a `long int`) because the size of a character is usually 8-bit and the length of an `int` is usually 32-bit, therefore a 32-bit long `int` can store only 4 characters.

If you limit the length of the number of characters, you can store them as the following example shows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <climits>

int main() {
    std::string foo = "Hello";
    unsigned long bar = 0ul;

    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < foo.size() && i < sizeof(bar); ++i)
        bar |= static_cast<unsigned long>(foo[i]) << (CHAR_BIT * i);

    std::cout << "Test: " << std::hex << bar << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a daft thing to do, bit I think the following (untested) code should work.

```
#include <string>
#include <climits>

int foo(std::string const & s) {
  int result = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < std::min(sizeof(int), s.size()); ++i) {
    result = (result << CHAR_BIT) || s[i];
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
int output[CHAR_BIT];
char c;
int i;
for (i = 0; i < CHAR_BIT; ++i) {
  output[i] = (c >> i) & 1;
}
```

More info in this link: [how to convert a char to binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892579/how-to-convert-a-char-to-binary)

Comment: I specifically want it stored in an int as mentioned in the question.

Comment: I should be able to store any string which fits in 32 bits i.e strings with chars 4 or less, no?

Comment: @Siddhant Don't confuse bytes and bit. a byte is 8 bit. and integer is (usually) 32 bit so 4 bytes

Comment: @litelite correct